# Change in microsoft documentation

Tags: sql-server

I am confused after microsoft changed the documentation style.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/active-secondaries-readable-secondary-replicas-always-on-availability-groups

Earlier we used to be able to change the version of sql server at the top of the page.  Now I just see this.
[image]

How do I change the version of document to SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Easy: there's no 2015 version for SQL Server ;)

Comment: I also want to ask a community if someone knows where can I complain about this "new" style? This "not to be able to change a version" feature must be voted down, why don't they leave an old-style documentation as well? If you offer a new product on a market and you want to promote it, you make an effort to make it better, so usera select the new one only if it's really better. But when you susbstitute the old one completely you leave no choice for users and this is bad.

Comment: These are two examples of misleading new-style documentation: the first one is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timestamp-transact-sql they write it's in use starting from SQL Server 2008, but it works fine at least from 2000; this is another one: BUCKUP TO URL, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url, "starting with 2016" but we successully back up to url using 2012. So what are they writing and for which purpose? At this point it's better not write a version at all

Answer (score 1):

From the same documentation:

> Beginning in SQL Server 2014, readable secondary replicas can remain
>   online even when the primary replica is offline due to user action or
>   a failure. However, read-only routing does not work in this situation
>   because the availability group listener is offline as well. Clients
>   must connect directly to the read-only secondary replicas for
>   read-only workloads.

So, you can go to 2014 because the article exists only for 2016.

Comment: Read only routing is available in 2014, so I am just trying to find where document for 2014 version of that document is.

Comment: @newguy were you looking for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-read-only-routing-for-an-availability-group-sql-server)? The article you found states that *the article* is only for 2016 (not *the feature*), but I agree this is not intuitive, nor is it that the article I posted doesn't state any version info at all (at least not on mobile). You used to be able to append major version/compat level to a URL `(sql.120)` for example, but seems like they've done away with that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of the new format myself, but in this scenario, you'll need to Google/Bing it out.

I suspect this is the link you're looking for:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878253(v=sql.120).aspx

I got there by looking at the root feature page for AGs on 2014 here,
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff877884(SQL.120).aspx, and then followed the legacy link trail...